# How to include GLUI framework in makefile on macbookpro?

Tags: c++, macos, glut, glui

I am using macbook pro that runs on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1. I downloaded and installed GLUI 2.35 framework from here [GLUI 2.35](https://lukecyca.com/2008/glui-235-framework-for-mac-os-x.html) and wrote a makefile to rum my c++ program but I got an error the no `<GLUI/glui.h>` can be found so I made a directory and included the glui.h file there:

```
/usr/inlcude/GLUI/glui.h
```

In the makefile I wrote:

```
FRAMEWORKS = (some other framewords I use) -framework GLUI
```

Then I got a linker error that framework GLUI is not found. 
I checked `/Library/Frameworks/` and indeed `GLUI.framework` is there. 
Am I not including GLUI framework correctly?

Answer (score 0):

the include is `#include <GL/glui.h>`. This is the case in most libraries you might want to double check that the header file is correctly `GL/glui.h`

Answer (score 0):

Failing to locate the installed GLUI framework occurred to me as well. After that, I tried to use the libglui.a and it just worked for me.

P.S. You could generate the library from the glui [source code](https://github.com/libglui/glui).